# Can i know the place where we can buy the stocks and bonds?

Tags: stocks, india, bonds, stock-markets

What do I need to trade in stocks and bonds.I don't know the actual place where it happens ( is it in banks, or some other place) and I don't know what is the process to hold and sell the stocks.

Comment: Please add a country tag, the world is a big place, and the brokers near me may not service your country too. More important, we have members all all the world, and I'm sure one with expertise will answer you.

Comment: The actual place where it happens? On the stock exchange's computers.

Answer (score 4):

To buy and sells Shares or Bonds you need three things;

1. Bank Account
2. Demat Account
3. Trading Account

You can have all the 3 from same Bank. Almost all leading Banks in India would offer these services. Or you can open 2 and 3 from a Broker firm, there are quite a few reputed ones.

The trading account will allow you to buy or sell shares, You can buy or sell from Internet login, by phone, by mobile App, visiting to main office in person.

The shares you buy are credited into your Demat Account. You can see the shares balance there.

The Bank account will be where either funds are debited or credited depending on whether you have purchased or sold the shares.